# Extract intervals inside groups in a dataframe , using information of another dataframe .

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

Like i said in the title, my purpose is to extract intervals of subset of my dataframe using information of another dataframe.

my input:

df1:

```
  subject         x      y
7G001-0024-10   0,00    15
7G001-0024-10   97,29   18
7G001-0024-10   197,34  21
7G001-0024-10   314,66  22
7G001-0024-10   482,77  25
7G001-0030-10   0,00    12
7G001-0030-10   99,50   16
7G001-0030-10   184,37  20
7G001-0030-10   301,89  25
7G001-0030-10   585,67  27
     ...         ...   ...
```

df2 :

```
    subject   Threshold 
7G001-0024-10   177,08
7G001-0030-10   385,13
    ...          ...
```

For each subject I would like to extract in the df1 the x and y data between 0 and the threshold value of each subject contain in df2 for get an output in this spirit :

```
  subject         x      y
7G001-0024-10   0,00    15
7G001-0024-10   97,29   18
7G001-0030-10   0,00    12
7G001-0030-10   99,50   16
7G001-0030-10   184,37  20
7G001-0030-10   301,89  25
    ...          ...   ...
```

My first idea , it was using which() inside ddply function :

```
break=ddply(df1,.(subject),summarize,fun=x[which(x>=0 & x<Threshold )])
```

but I am stuck , I didn't see how to indicate the changement of my Threshold (df2) inside the which function.

Well, if anybody can tell me how deal with it (with my first intuition or not )

Sorry for the poor English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your data:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "subject         x      y
7G001-0024-10   0,00    15
7G001-0024-10   97,29   18
7G001-0024-10   197,34  21
7G001-0024-10   314,66  22
7G001-0024-10   482,77  25
7G001-0030-10   0,00    12
7G001-0030-10   99,50   16
7G001-0030-10   184,37  20
7G001-0030-10   301,89  25
7G001-0030-10   585,67  27", header = TRUE, dec = ",")

df2 <- read.table(text = "subject   Threshold 
7G001-0024-10   177,08
7G001-0030-10   385,13", header = TRUE, dec = ",")
```

You can use simple `apply` to solve the task:

```
do.call("rbind", apply(df2, 1, FUN = function(a) {df1[a[1] == df1$subject & df1$x >= 0 & df1$x <= as.numeric(a[2]), ]}))

#         subject      x  y
# 1 7G001-0024-10   0.00 15
# 2 7G001-0024-10  97.29 18
# 6 7G001-0030-10   0.00 12
# 7 7G001-0030-10  99.50 16
# 8 7G001-0030-10 184.37 20
# 9 7G001-0030-10 301.89 25
```

---

### How does it work?

First, the function `apply(df2, 1, FUN)` applies a function to each row in the data frame `df2`. The value `1` means that the function is applied to the 1st dimension of the object (the second dimension would be columns).

Have a look at a simple function. It just returns the first and second row of `df2`. Note that in the output, the rows are arranged as columns.

```
> apply(df2, 1, FUN = function(a) a)
          [,1]            [,2]           
subject   "7G001-0024-10" "7G001-0030-10"
Threshold "177.08"        "385.13"
```

Since we want to extract a subset of `df1` a more complex function is needed. So, I specified:

```
FUN = function(a) {df1[a[1] == df1$subject & df1$x >= 0 & df1$x <= as.numeric(a[2]), ]}
```

In this function, `a` represents a row of the data frame `df2`. This function is aplied two times, once for both rows of `df2`. `a[1]` is the subject number, `a[2]` is the corresponding threshold.
The function extracts a subset of rows of the data frame `df1` by three criteria:

1. The subjects are identical (`a[1] == df1$subject`)
2. The `x` value is at least zero (`df1$x >= 0`)
3. The `x` value is not higher than the threshold (`df1$x <=
   as.numeric(a[2])`)

Note: The value `a[2]` needs to be transformed to a number by `as.numeric`. This is necessary since the subject id in `df2` is represented as character and thereby `apply` converts the whole row (including the threshold value) into characters.

Each of these criteria returns a logical vector. These vectors are combined with `&` into a single logical vector indicating whether all three criteria are fullfilled. With `df1[logical.vector, ]` all rows of `df1` where the logical vector is `TRUE` are selected. Since nothing is specified after the `,`, all columns are selected.

The rows of `df1` for which all three criterial are fullfilled are returned by the `apply` function.

```
> apply(df2, 1, FUN = function(a) {df1[a[1] == df1$subject & df1$x >= 0 & df1$x <= as.numeric(a[2]), ]})
[[1]]
        subject     x  y
1 7G001-0024-10  0.00 15
2 7G001-0024-10 97.29 18

[[2]]
        subject      x  y
6 7G001-0030-10   0.00 12
7 7G001-0030-10  99.50 16
8 7G001-0030-10 184.37 20
9 7G001-0030-10 301.89 25
```

The function `apply` returns a list of two data frames, one for each row of `df2`.

In the last step, the data frames in the list are combined into one data frame. The function `do.call("rbind", list)` executes the function `rbind` and passes the arguments in the list to it. For a list of length 2, this is equivalent to `rbind(list[[1]], list[[2]])`. In this way, both data frames in the list returned by `apply`are combined.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer , it's works fine ! if it is not too much to ask can you comment your code ? thank in advance .

Comment: I updated my answer with an additional section ("How does it work?").